# Accepted answer is removed (edited to make it like a comment)

Tags: discussion

I have faced an unusual situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545226/how-do-i-use-uniqid-to-generate-a-6-chars-length-id).

If you will check the accepted answer, the member has removed the answer. Maybe the comment is referring to a better answer, but still he could have edited his/her answer and also could have given a message to read the answer he want to recommend, but is it the correct way?

Should we flag to delete answer like this?

Comment: They're not deletable, not even by mods I think.  Hence the weird situation.

Comment: You could eat some ice cream, for example. Or enjoy a brisk walk in the sun. :) Seriously though - I don't think there is anything we can do, apart from asking the asker to change their check mark (but usually in these types of situations that has already happened.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 thank you, I am just going to put a comment for the asker.

Comment: @Pekka웃: I'd be really surprised if mods couldn't delete accepted answers. It would be so easy to abuse...

Comment: As said, I don't think there is anything we can do.

Comment: @Pekka웃: we can delete it, but usually only do so if requested by the OP.

Comment: @user000001 what  you suggest here ?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have left an comment for the asker.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if OP is not so active , is there any choice ?

Comment: The flag "the answer is removed" is not very helpful to moderators. Try to add some context; like *the author removed the contents of this answer, which is marked as accepted. Can a moderator restore the content or delete the post?* would be far more helpful. Tell us what you want us to do.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: the author is active.

Comment: @MartijnPieters deleting will be more helpful , as people will go for max voted solution or ask a question with reference to this post . but there are other community members may suggest something better , I would like to know .

Comment: @MartijnPieters the user is last seen 28th sept 2015 before some months .

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, I would count what the OP did as a naive and misguided try try to delete his accepted answer. That cries for a comment to guide him and finishing it...

Comment: @Deduplicator: the answerer should not have vandalised their answer like that, no.

Comment: Once a post is accepted as an answer, the poster can do very little to fix a problem with the post.  Deleting such a post is not possible, moderators usually refuse a request to delete it and insist that the post is updated instead.  Which is what he did, directing the reader to another more correct answer.  Hassling the poster about it or restoring his incorrect answer is not productive.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: I was talking about the author of the answer, not the author of the question. The answerer was active today (and no, that's not moderator-only info).

Comment: @Deduplicator: They could have updated their post with an addendum, or warning about the drawbacks, and then point to another answer. They replaced the whole answer, so the other post is now also referencing a vacuum.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You may have suggested him to edit his answer , that will be great . :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Isn't replacing the complete answer a form of self vandalism and can be dealt with by rolling back / locking the thing?

Comment: I think the code should be added back the the comment from the OP to not use it should stay.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mods have the power to delete accepted answers and may be willing to do so in response to flags, but many users, [including some very experienced ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316170/accepted-answer-is-removed-edited-to-make-it-like-a-comment?cb=1#comment302954_316170), don't know this.

As a result, it's reasonably common to find an accepted answer whose author has expressed a clear desire to delete it - either by editing out all the content from the post and replacing it with "use [other guy's answer](http://example.com) instead", as in this case, or by posting a comment lamenting that they'd like to delete the answer but are unable to do so. These users don't know that they have mod flags available to them to solve their problem.

In such cases:

- First, review whether the post (or the original version) is actually *good*, in the sense that you think it is helpful and would upvote it. If so, revert any edits that vandalise it and leave it alone. Users aren't supposed to destroy useful content, even if they authored it.
- If the post genuinely is bad, ***and*** the author has either stripped all content from the post or has clearly expressed their desire to have it deleted, then flag the post for moderator attention, *clearly stating that the author has asked for the post to be deleted* and pointing out where they've said that. A moderator will likely delete the post; I've never had a flag of this type rejected.

Comment: You represented the situation and all the discussion really well, thank you for this , your effort is really appreciable.

Comment: We should not have to request (and wait) our own content be deleted if we think it below standard or embarrassing for example.  It is a matter of ownership.  If I wish to be disassociated from my own work, I should have that right.  If I wish my own work to be taken down, I should have that right.  If I provided incorrect information and a naïve user accepted it, that affects my reputation (in the real world in not on SO).  This is insidious,